# Live-stream video from one android phone to another via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, filestream

I am intended to make an app that stream live videos from one android phone to other one via Bluetooth,i need a simple player and there is no need to save the file,just play it.
My knowledge about stream in java is not enough and I really don't know where to start!
Please help me in finding any solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample android project to do streaming live video and allows you take photos and record videos from remote phone via bluetooth.

[BluetoothCameraAndroid](https://github.com/sujithkanna/BluetoothCameraAndroid)

Android allows you to get frames as byte array using camera, you can use that api to get frames and send it across. But the problem is throttling the sending rate. That also has been handled in that project.

> In marshmallow and above devices, you have to give permissions
>   manually in settings. This project does not include runtime
>   permissions

Answer (score 0):

Xuggler is a Java opensource library that works with streaming and modifying media on the fly. you can start from it at:

> http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/